# Show entries based on Grid field

Tags: channel-entries, grid

I'de like to show only entries that have gridfield:total_rows > 0

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having given this some more thought, this would be a much simpler approach...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name"}
{if '{grid_field}{grid_field:count}{/grid_field}' > 0}
{title} - {grid_field}{grid_field:count}{/grid_field}<br/>
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```